# Организация дедупликации для облачных хранилищ

Tags: storage, azure-storage, amazon-s3

Интересуюсь программными решениями которые могут помочь организовать блочную дедупликацию данных сохраняя их в Azure BLOB storage / Google Storage / Amazon s3, то есть программное решение представляет собой прослойку между неким приложением (предоставляя api) и уже само разбивает входные данные на блоки и сохраняет блоки в хранилище и также где-то хранит наборы ссылок их которых собирается оригинальный файл и при этом каждый блок загруженный в хранилище является уникальным.